# What's a word for "teenager-ish"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for a word that encapsulates "teenager-ish" - that sort of petulant, contrarian, immature behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: teenager-ish seems to fill the bill

Comment: Adolescent behavior?

Comment: The chosen answer is related to childish more than teenagerish. Or too general. You could just ask childish or immature behavior without mentioning teenagerish at all then.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Juvenile**: [immature; childish; infantile: His juvenile tantrums are not in keeping with his age.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/juvenile)

**Sophomoric**: [2. childish, adolescent, juvenile](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sophomoric).

Comment: I think sophomoric gets it across very well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it works for English, but in France we refer to that kind of behavior as "[**adulescent**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=vrRbTKnrcZUC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22adulescents+are%22&source=bl&ots=qJpTptBZk5&sig=sXqukC-OmSXB1bg3OFvzR6rfYMQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=U3NhU4HEPKfB0gXTuYGYCQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22adulescents%20are%22&f=false)," a neologistic blend of "adult" and "adolescent."

Consider also "[**teenish**](http://www.angelfire.com/nc2/random4/inspite.html),"  "[**Peterpannish**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=KJW-NdyUytkC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=%22peterpannish%22&source=bl&ots=wzaUV4KsGM&sig=eU50Uu35RfO7srwu0MsixEJ_IV4&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=fEFhU7K8EML1ObrPgIgD&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22peterpannish%22&f=false)," "[**cubbish**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cub)," and "[**jejune**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jejune)."

Comment: I've never seen "adulescent" before, but I like it.

Comment: Swedish uses *fjortis*, behaving like a fourteen year old (fjortonåringen)

Answer (score 0):

**Bratty** covers the type of traits you're talking about, although it's often used of younger children.

Answer (score 0):

**[adolescently](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adolescently)** if you are looking for an adverb

> In a adolescent manner; like a teenager.

[**adolescent**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adolescent) itself is an adjective also, meaning:

> Characteristic of adolescence; immature: *an adolescent sense of humor.*

I focused on the word teenager though, because it is different than being child. So teenagerish would be different than childish. Though they are both immature.